# I keep getting an uncaught error - undefined is not a function when trying to create a settings screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**I have everything wrapped in a navigation container. The first 5 screens are set up as a bottom tab navigator. I want the settings screen as a separate screen where I click on a settings button in the profile screen.**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();


const RootNavigation = () => {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Loop" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={BottomTabNavigator} /> //Profile screen is the rendering the "Score" component 
                <Stack.Screen name="Compete" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Diss" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Feedback" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>

    );
};

export default RootNavigation;
```

**I have created a separate file called "SettingsNavigator.js"**

```
const SettingsNavigator = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name={"Settings"} component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      
    );
  };
export default SettingsNavigator;
```

**Then in my screens folder I have a Settings screen rendering the SettingsPage**

```
const Settings = () => {
    return (
        <View> 
            <SettingsPage />
        </View>
    
    );
};

export default Settings;
```

**My components folder has the SettingsPage as follows**

```
const SettingsPage = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello this is the settings page</Text>
        </View>
    );
 };
export default SettingsPage;
```

**Lastly, My profile screen has an icon touchableopacity button that I want to be able to press and render the The SettingsPage to read the text: Hello this is the settings page. BUT this is when I click the settings button I get an error reading:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes

```
const Score = () => {
return (

    <View style={{
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height, 
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width, 
                backgroundColor: '#1c1c1c'
                }}>
    
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.settings}>
            <Ionicons 
            name={'settings-outline'} 
            size={30} 
            color='white'
            onPress={() => Navigation.navigate('SettingsPage') }
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
</View>

    
    );
};

export default Score;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the normal navigation hook from react native, I can see that you didn't import the hook and initialize it.

I think you need to import it from `node_modules`:

`import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';`

and inside your component initialize the navigation object using the hook:

`const navigation = useNavigation();`

then you should be good.

note that I use navigation with a lowercase n here

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the major couple of lines in your **Score Screen** No issues follow this ,

```js
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';  //Add this Import

const Score = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();  //Add this Line

  return (
    <View style={{
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      backgroundColor: '#1c1c1c'
    }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.settings}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}> // Change 'Navigation' to 'navigation'
        <Ionicons
          name={'settings-outline'}
          size={30}
          color='white'
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Score;
```

I have assumed all other imports from the code you have provided .After these changes , your code will work fine.